# Move an iterator with a reference into a thread

Tags: multithreading, rust, closures

I have a type that represents a file. For simplicity lets say the type holds a buffer with the contents of the file.

There is also a method for building an iterator which holds a reference to the internal buffer.

The file-type is created on the main thread, but I need to "send" the iterator into the thread.

Let me show what I am trying to do

```rust
struct FileType {...}

let mut my_file_type = FileType::new("some_filename");
let mut my_iterator = my_file_type.iter();

external_library_object.start_process(move|_| {
    for _ in (0..10) {
        println!(my_iterator.next().unwrap());
    }
}
```

`external_library_object` (which by the way is cpal's device) is... well an object from a library I can't change. The closure parameter implements Send trait though.

This doesn't work because `my_file_type` doesn't live long enough.
So I tried a combination of Mutex (so the iterator is mutable) and Arc(so we share the iterator between the 2 threads)

```rust
...

let mut my_file_type = FileType::new("some_filename");
let mut my_iterator = Arc::new(Mutex::new(my_file_type.iter()));

external_library_object.start_process(move|_| {
    let mut cloned = my_iterator.clone();
    for _ in (0..10) {
        println!(cloned.lock().unwrap().next().unwrap());
    }
}
```

But again, this doesn't work. I get an error similar to this:

```rust
xx |     let mut my_iterator = Arc::new(Mutex::new(my_file_type.iter()));
   |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^-------
   |                                                   |
   |                                                   borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                                                   argument requires that `my_file_type` is borrowed for `'static`
...
xx | }
   | - `my_file_type` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I am kind of stuck here. Is there a way to use the iterator which has a reference to other object(a buffer in this case) inside a different thread?

Edit: In my specific case the itertor is infinite and the closure executes multiple times. That is the reason I can't move the entire FileType inside the thread.

Comment: You could share the file between the threads rather than the iterator. Or make the iterator consume the file.

Comment: The problem with that is that the closure executes multiple times. Actually you just made me see the sample code is not as accurate. Let me update that

Comment: The issue you're running into is that `my_iterator` holds a reference to `my_file_type`, but `my_file_type` gets dropped at the end of the main thread and `my_iterator` might still exist in the secondary thread. You need the Arc(Mutex()) on `my_file_type` because that's the underlying data. You'll be forced to hold the mutex for as long as the iterator exists in either thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky, because the process borrows an iterator, which in turn borrows a struct. Putting just the iterator into an `Arc<Mutex<>>` is not sufficient, because this pointer might still outlive the `FileType` it borrows. However, we can't put both the `FileType` and the iterator into a reference-counted struct, since that struct would then be self-referential.

The easiest solution to this that I can think of (short of using [scoped threads](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.0/crossbeam/thread/index.html)) is to create an iterator that *owns* the `FileType`, and then put it into a `Arc<Mutex<>>` ([minimal playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=354ec638d3931a1eee02cdd79c14bbdc)):

```rust
let my_file_type = FileType::new("test!");
let my_iterator = Arc::new(Mutex::new(my_file_type.into_iter()));

external_library_object.start_process(move |_| {
    for _ in 0..10 {
        println!("{:?}", my_iterator.lock().unwrap().next().unwrap());
    }
});
```

You just have to implement an owned iterator for your `FileType` struct, if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: It seems this is the only solution that works. I was hoping I wouldn't need to implement the IntoIterator trait.